# In MATLAB, how do I pull out p eigenvectors corresponding to the p largest eigenvalues?

Tags: matlab, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I'm currently using the command: [V, D] = eig(X)

Where V are the eigenvectors and D are the eigenvalues in a diagonal matrix. Any idea on how I can create Y, a matrix of eigenvectors corresponding to the p largest eigenvalues?

Comment: if `p` is small, consider `eigs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to eigs:

```
[V,D] = eigs(A,size(A,1)-1)
```

Second way is to sort:

```
if ~issorted(diag(D))
    [V,D] = eig(A);
    [D,I] = sort(diag(D));
    V = V(:, I);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p=3;  %'as a example say we want the eigenvectors for the 3 largest eigenvalues'

X=rand(4); %'take whatever matrix 4x4 for the example'

[V, D] = eig(X);

for ind=1:length(D)
    d(ind)=abs(D(ind,ind));
end

[B,IX] = sort(d,'descend');

Y = V(:,IX(1:p));
```

The columns of Y contain the eigenvectors that correspond to the eigenvalues in descending order from, left to right.
Notice that I used the abs() function to measure the "size" of the eigenvalue.  Beware that perhaps you prefer to use some other function.

Comment: Why use a for loop and not just `[~, IX] = sort(abs(diag(D)))` or rather `[V,D] = eig(X,'vector'); [~, IX] = sort(abs(D))`?